# Incenter excenter lemma

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have to prove that $BD=DI_A$. I know that therefore $I_A$ must be the intersection of the external bisectors, but how do I prove that?

Comment: You question is unclear because you do not define of $D$ is constructed: Do you want to prove that the midpoint of $I$ and $I_A$, "called $D$", belongs to the circumscribed circle of the triangle, or more than that with your green circle ?

Comment: D is the midpoint of minor arc BC

Comment: @CauchytheDog isn't D just obtained by extending the line joining incenter and the vertex A, to cut the circumcircle?

Comment: No because the first question was to prove that D lies on the angle bisector of angle A

Comment: @CauchytheDog please clarify the entire construction in words in the question

Comment: 1) When you answer to somebody, please begin by @somebody, in order that he/she knows there is an answer for him/her. 2) Please, modify your question as asked by Arkya Chatterjee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\angle  BIC=90+\frac{A}{2}$ \angle at incentre

$\implies \angle BI_AC=90-\frac{A}{2}$    $BICI_A$ is cyclic qudrilateral

& $\angle BDC =180-A$. \ in cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$

As$\angle BDC=2\angle BI_AC$

so $D$ is centre of green circle. someone can say that any point on the circumcircle would satisfy angle relation so observe that D is mid point of arc so it also satisfy radius property in green circle.

So  $BD=BI_A$ both are radius of green circle

Comment: How do you get that $\angle BI_A C=90-A/2$

Comment: From cyclic quadrilateral$ BICI_A$

Comment: but that isn't given

Comment: I need to prove that B I C and IA lie on the circle with midpoint D

Comment: Then what is $I_A$

Comment: the intersection of the angle bisector of angle A with the circumcircle of bci

Comment: Then obviously cyclic quadrilateral is given

Comment: You are saying that IA is intersection with circle then why cyclicity is not considered by you

Comment: Do you know a way to prove it by using isosceles triangle $BDI_A$?

Comment: Hi @Blaise, your solution is right. I just would recommend you explain a bit more every step. In that way you can help more people to understand faster your solution.

Comment: I think it would be more readable for all